# Counterstrike Global Offensive Danger Zone: How many bullets to kill a drone?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Recently Counterstrike Global Offensive came out with a game mode called Danger Zone which is their spin on battle royale.

There is an interesting mechanic where you can buy items and a drone delivers a package to you. This drone gets spawned randomly on the map on the outside and flies to you meaning other players can shoot it to take your loot or you can follow the drone to find the player.

Perhaps I'm just bad but I can't really confirm how many bullets it takes to shoot down a drone. It seems to teeter and fall a little but then goes and continues to fly again.

Does anybody know? Or any other methods to shoot down the drones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I set up a server in CS:GO using these commands:

```
game_mode 0
game_type 6
map dz_blacksite (I used blacksite as the test map)
sv_cheats 1
```

I used this command to spawn drones:

```
ent_create drone
```

And this command to drop weapons:

```
give weapon_"weaponname"
```

Using these commands I found the **minimum number of bullets** it took for each weapon to shoot down a drone.

#### Pistols

- Took 3 bullets: USP-silenced and unsilenced, P2000, Glock, Dual Beretta, Five Seven, Tec-9, CZ-75
- Took 2 bullets: p250, Deagle
- Took 1 bullet: Revolver

#### SMGs

- Took 4 bullets: Bizon
- Took 3 bullets: MAC-10, MP7, MP9, P90, UMP45, MP5

#### Heavy Weapons

- Took 3 bullets: M249, Negev
- Took 1 pellet: MAG-7, Nova, Sawed-Off, XM1014

#### Rifles

- Took 3 bullets: M4A1-Silenced and unsilenced, M4A4, AUG, SG553, Galil, Famas
- Took 2 bullets: AK47
- Took 1 bullet: G3SG1, SCAR-20, SSG-08, AWP

#### Some interesting observations:

- Distance was not a factor for bullets needed
- If the drone bounced off a ceiling of some sort before you shot your 1st bullet, it reduced the required bullets by 1 for all weapons (except for the weapons that are 1 hit of course)
- Being in the red Danger Zone does not affect the drone or the amount of bullets taken

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just shot one with about 10 bullets from P90 still flew off

Answer (score -1):

not a lot, 5-6 hits with a pistol. If gun- less. but its better to follow it find enemy and kill